# Find triplet for set, Python

Tags: python, math, set, triplet

This is my assignment:

> ### Find the triplet a, b, c ∈ {x | x ∈ Z and 450 > x > 0}
>
> #### Such that the following relations is satisfied:
>
> 1. a = if b is even: c+11 BUT
>      if b is odd: 2c-129
> 2. b = (a * c) mod 2377
> 3. c = (Sum of b-7k from k=0 to a-1) + 142

This is what I've tried so far:

**Alternative 1:**

```
for a in range(1,449):
    for b in range(1, 449):
        for c in range(1, 449):

            #a
            if b%2==0:
                a=c+11

            elif b%2!=0:
                a=2*c-129

            #b
            b = (a*c)%2377


            #c
            k = 0
            c0=0
            upper = a-1
            for i in range(0, upper+1):
                c0 = b-7*i
                #k+=1
            c = c0 + 142
            print a, b, c
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
def a_func(x):
    if (b_func(x)%2==0):
        return c_func(x)+11
    else:
        return 2*c_func(x)-129

def b_func(x):
    return a_func(x)*c_func(x) % 2377

def c_func(x):
    k=0
    c0=0
    upper = a_func(x)-1
    for i in range(0, upper+1):
        c0 = b_func(x) - 7 * k
        k+=1
    return c0+142

def all(x):
    return a_func(x), b_func(x), c_func(x)

for x in range(1, 449):
    print all(x)
```

None of them seem to work.

Comment: Ask your teacher. We are not going to do your assignment for you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show a little more effort. The first program prints 449*449*449 lines of output. There is clearly something totally wrong.

The idea behind the the task is, that you have to check, if the three equations hold or not.

So the main program can be of the following structure:

```
for a in range(1,449):
    for b in range(1, 449):
        for c in range(1, 449):
            if equation_one_holds and equation_two_holds and equation_three_holds:
                print a, b, c
```

Your task now is to implements the checks. As a hint, `equation_two_holds` could be `(b == (a * c) % 2377)`. The checks for `equaltion_one_holds` and `equation_three_holds` are a little bit more complicated, but with a little bit of effort, you can manage it.

Comment: Python would still need to do the calculations 449*449*449 times to output one answer? 
I followed your example and it has been running for quite a while now. Do you have a better way to program this?

Comment: You could only loop over `a` and `b` and calculate `c` with the values of `a` and `b`. Then the third equation is automatically true, and you only have to loop 449*449 times.

Comment: So, this is my if-statement:
`if (a==c+11 if b%2==0 else a==2*c-129) and (b==(a*c)%2377) and (c==c0+142):`, where c is calculated with this for-loop earlier in the code: `for i in range(0, upper+1):
            c0 = b-7*k
            k+=1` with the variables k, c0, c=0 and upper = a-1 set in the beginning.

Comment: I guess `c0 += b - 7*k`.

Comment: `c0 = sum(b-7*k for k in range(a)) + 142` and `if (a==c+11 if b%2==0 else a==2*c-129) and (b==(a*c)%2377) and (c==c0):print(a,b,c)` works for me.

Comment: It's slow, but finds a solution after 2 minutes.

Comment: Hm, do you have any initial values for k, c0 or c in the beginning?

Comment: No, I did the 3 loops like in the answer, and then these 2 lines. 
Alternative you can do the faster version: 
`for a in range(1,449):
    for b in range(1, 449):
        c = sum(b-7*k for k in range(a)) + 142
        if (a==c+11 if b%2==0 else a==2*c-129) and (b==(a*c)%2377):
            print(a,b,c)`

Comment: It seems I can't upvote due to lack of reputation points, but I did however tick your answer.